# Access Database in CodeIgniter Template

Tags: php, mysql, database, codeigniter, codeigniter-2

If I am setting up my template for every page as such how would I make a database call and send it as a parameter to my `topNav` page?

```
$template['user']['template'] = 'user/u.template.php';
$template['user']['regions'] = array(
   'title'      => array('content' => ""),
   'projectName'=> array('content' => ''),
   'topNav'     => array('content' => $this->CI->load->view('nav/topnav.php', NULL, TRUE)),
   'subNav'     => array('content' => $this->CI->load->view('nav/subnav.php', NULL, TRUE)),
//'footer'     => array('content' => $this->CI->load->view('user/parts/footer.v.php', NULL, TRUE)),
   'content'    => array('content' => "content")

);
```

I tried to do something like so:

`$announcements = $this->db->get('announcements');` but I get,

> Message: Undefined property: MY_Loader::$db
>
> Filename: config/template.php

Comment: Did you autoload the database library?

Comment: It's loaded into all models, but I'm not sure about config/template.php

Comment: Rather than loading it in all models try auto loading it in config/autoload.php  in the libraries area.

Comment: `$autoload['libraries'] = array('database', 'MY_Model', 'session', 'auth', 'table', 'form_validation');`

Comment: Is the template.php file a config file or a library file? I am not sure that you could load view in config file.

Comment: if this is in view its **wrong**